# SQL joins on Null values

Tags: sql-server, join

Hi I have 2 tables A and B

Table A has 2 columns a1 (int) and a2(varchar(5))
Table B has 2 columns b1 (int) and b2(varchar(5))

Table A has values as

```
a1     a2
1      aaa
NULL   bbb
2      ccc
3      ddd
```

Table B has Values as

```
b1     b2
1      app
2      new
3      disc
```

I want to get the result as

```
a1     a2      b2
1      aaa     app
NULL   bbb     NULL
2      ccc     new
3      ddd     disc
```

Note--

Bear in mind Im joining a1 with b1 but a1 has NULL and I want Null as well in my result.

Comment: You should choose what database you are using.  MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Any reason you want Null as a primary key?

Comment: Got my answer guys!! Thanks heaps for your time. My requirement is not exactly the same as I have jotted down. Probably improper explanation. But, thanks heaps for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called a `LEFT JOIN` to achieve these results. I interpret it's functionality as:

> Give me rows from the table on the left and if any rows from the table on the right fulfill my conditions, join them. Otherwise use `NULL` values in their place.

So if you say `SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ...`, `A` is on the left and will hence always be selected. `B` on the right will only be used if the `ON` condition is satisfied. If it isn't, then `NULL` will be used in place of it's values, giving you exactly what you wanted!

I'd just like to point out that things might get weird if `B` ever has a `NULL` value for `b1`. As such, I'd add a check like this:

```
SELECT a1, a2, b2
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
  ON a1 IS NOT NULL AND a1 = b1;
```

You can see the fiddle running here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca6d/5

EDIT: That null thing doesn't seem to cause any problems in MySQL 5.6 since `NULL = NULL` is false (and so is `NULL != NULL`), but I'd feel weird leaving it unaccounted for..

Answer (score 0):

A `left join` should do what you want:

```
select a.a1, a.a2, b.b2
from a left join
     b
     on a.a1 = b.b1;
```

This is standard SQL so it will work in any database.

Comment: @wewesthemenace . . . It looks like malicious downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for a `left join`

```
select tablea.*, tableb.b2 from
  tablea left join tableb
    on tablea.a1 = tableb.b1
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a937/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
select A.a1,A.a2,B.b2 from A left join B on A.a1 = B.b1;
```